# How do we respond to tag question after urgings starting with 'Let's'?

Tags: american-english, question-tags, learning

There is a question bothering me. It is about an acceptable response to a tag question following *Let's ...*

The following example is from [English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-questions-tag-special.htm):

> A: "Let's go, shall we?"
>
> B: "________."

How should (B) answer A, maintaining correct parallelism??

Compare the below example, where B replies "Yes, we can".

> A: "We can go out, can't we?"
>
> B: "Yes, we can."

I am not looking for workarounds like like "Sure."

Comment: "Yes,/;/ – / ... let's." or "OK,/; let's."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Edwin Ashworth's comment although I'm not sure about the necessity for a semicolon.

**My answer**

A: "Let's go, shall we?"

B: "Yes let's."

If pushed I might insert a comma and say, "Yes, let's" but personally I find that unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not sure how "Yes, let's" would sound to a British ear, but in the U.S. it would sound jarringly old-fashioned.

Comment: I think the point is that we have been asked not to answer with 'Sure' or 'Okay'. How would you say it?

Comment: I wouldn't answer it with the tag structure at all; I would use a workaround. However, since OP specifically said he didn't want a workaround, I just thought he should know that the tag response, while correct, might not sound natural in all settings.

Comment: There's also structures like "Don't let's..." that I've seen in older books but never actually heard anyone say. Again, I don't know about BrE, but in AmE, something like "Don't let's argue" would sound old-fashioned; people would say "Let's not argue" instead.

Comment: I can imagine saying, "Yes - Let's go!", but I'm not sure that counts as a tag.

Comment: It's not a tag. The tag is the _shall we?_ part. This is a very strange tag, but then _Let's_ sentences are very strange sentences. They start with an imperative and tag questions require a declarative; if we treated _Let's go to the movies_ as a declarative, its tag would be _, don't you?_. Instead, we get a completely unrelated verb (_shall_) which otherwise has few other uses in English (only in invitations, offers, and suggestions).

Comment: I looked at the website and some of the examples are downright weird...but apparently it's maintained by a native speaker.

Comment: @JohnLawler - If you read carefully, the question was not about the tag. It was about a suitable response to the tag.  EDIT - Ah I see that my previous comment was in error. Point taken.

Comment: More about tags and their oddities in this freshman college grammar problem (or, as I call these now I don't hafta grade them, a [grammar puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tags.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

My U.S. answer:

A: "Let's go, shall we?"

B: "Yes, let's!"

It doesn't sound old-fashioned or jarring to me, as it did to Nicole, but maybe it's a generational thing.